# Generic Class error: Argument of type is assignable to the constraint of type T, but T could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a Class like this

```
type BaseConfig = {
  url: string;
};

class HttpClient<T extends BaseConfig> {
  request(config: T): string {
    return 'some response';
  }

  // No TS error
  getRequest(url: string, config: T) {
    return this.request({
      ...config,
      url,
    });
  }
  getRequestWithOptionalConfig(url: string, config?: T) {
    // TS error: Argument of type '{ url: string }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
    // '{ url: string }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',
    // but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseConfig'.
    return this.request({
      ...config,
      url,
    });
  }
}
```

Method `getRequest(url: string, config: T)` is fine, but `getRequestWithOptionalConfig(url: string, config?: T)` yield error

> Argument of type '{ url: string }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.  '{ url: string }' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T',  but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'BaseConfig'.

How can I solve the problem without casting? [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgYQPYDsBmBLA5lAXigG8AoKKAVwCcAbALigWGu3VwG5SBfL0gY1qIEUABLBgYZLWwR0wADwAVKBAAewOQBMR8JGix4AfCXJR%20GZtUr9gqagAoAlCW6kz1CAEdKEZg4tDXEYlJ0YrNnwyCgpPYBp0KAByBFQAW2hPBDBLCCSuCjczXAhgACVvX38aBiYWSIAacwwcYKhQ0xioOISoYAALbAQAOk8fP2AHaK6oYbnA1oazLpqlru4nAqgiihLyyomAdWwBgHkwYGwMOFoDVoca8Pr2JoW8AH4Ql2nY0t6BoajA7%20H4xObDN64NYzVbLbabMxuNxAA)

Comment: I am not a Typescript expert, but believe it's complaining because `config?` can be null. I'd try `T | null` for the arg type.

Comment: @Genre Tried. It doesn't work though

Comment: Imagine someone writes `new HttpClient<{url: string, foo: number}>()` and calls `getRequestWithOptionalConfig("")`; should that be acceptable?  If so, then `request()` doesn't actually need a `T` (since it would be missing `foo`) and you should change the input type to just `{url: string}`.  If not, then `getRequestWithOptionalConfig` needs to know about some *default* config of type `T` to use in that case.  Which is it?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is request(..) needs to be called with a T type. Since T extends BaseConfig it could possibly have **more** fields than just URL.

However if you call `getRequestWithOptionalConfig` without the config parameter your would call it with an object **only** containing the url. So the possible additional fields are missing.

There come two possibilities to fix this to my mind.

**Solution 1**

Make HttpClient abstract and add this function:

```
abstract createDefaultConfig(): T
```

and use it like this

```
getRequestWithOptionalConfig(url: string, config?: T) {
    return this.request({
      ...config,
      ...this.createDefaultConfig()
    });
  }
```

**Solution 2**

Very similar but instead of the abstract function add this parameter to the constructor:

```
constructor(private createDefaultConfig: () => T) {}
```

and use it the same way Solution 1 does.

There might be a better solution, but I thought I use this answer to outline why the the error happens. Btw a cast would not be a great way since again, you could have an object not containing all the necessary fields.